# Query Audio Picker Intent in Android 11 returns empty

Tags: android, audio, android-intent, picker, android-11

To check if I have an audio picker on the device so I can show a list of pickers, I query the list of pickers then show intent, it was working on Android 10, but stopped working on Android 11 (resInfoList is empty):

AndroidManifest code :

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
        <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Kotlin Code:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 

MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
                                    val resInfoList = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0)
// this is empty in Android 11, but has items in Android 10`enter code here`
                                    if (resInfoList.isNotEmpty()) {
                                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""), 0)

                                }
```

The strange point is if I look for video files, it works properly and displays pickers:

AndroidManifest code :

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
        <data android:mimeType="video/*" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Kotlin Code:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
                                val resInfoList = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0)
                                if (resInfoList.isNotEmpty()) {
                                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""), 0)
                                }
```

Comment: I cannot explain why the second one works. Your `<queries>` structure does not match the `Intent`. Try removing `android:mimeType` and adding `android:scheme="content"` and `android:host="*"`.

Comment: Even adding scheme and host doesn't fix it, I remind it's working in Android 10, but not in 11. @CommonsWare